# how to Hardcode the filenames to send them to server?

Tags: html, file, node.js, file-upload

I want to send some files( images) to the server using NODEJS. But I don't want to use the regular input file tag to attach files. So, how can I hard code the filepaths to send them to servers from a HTML client? Is there any solutions? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you intend to do?
Do you just need to store the file path (i.e. you don't want to upload at all)? Or you want to upload the files via a different method but still use the file tag for selecting the file paths?

Comment: I want to upload files using different file selection method , other than the input file tag.. N later upload it.. To be precisely I want to hardcode them..

Comment: I agree with @duskwuff below. This is not allowed due to client browser security. I am not sure if Flash allows you to do this without user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

File input fields cannot be populated automatically -- the user must pick a file to upload themselves.